# What does 'with' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does 'with' mean in the following context?

> A LAN encompasses two or more computers connected over a server. The two important technologies involved in this network are Ethernet and Wi-fi.  **It ranges up to 2km & transmission speed is very high with easy maintenance and low cost.**

Does it mean 'and'?

Comment: Did you look for the meaning of 'with' in a dictionary? If so, which one, and what don't you understand about what you found?

Comment: It means has easy A and B. What is your native language?

Comment: Chinese. So in this context, Is 'with' equality to 'and'?
If it is right, so 'The good tv has a higher definition with a bigger screen' is right?

Comment: with preposition 1. accompanied by (another person or thing). 2. having or possessing (something). Here you need meaning (1).

Comment: Replacing "with" with "and" here wouldn't make any sense. "transmission speed is very high and easy maintenance" would be like saying the "transmission speed is easy maintenance" which is nonsense. "with easy maintenance and low cost" describes things that accompany the range and speed.